# What does __gnu_linux__ stand for?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, gnu, preprocessor

### Background

We have some old C++ code that contains a section that is only compiled if the preprocessor symbol `__gnu_linux__` is defined. Compiling on my Ubuntu 20.04 with GCC 9.3 is not a problem. Now, we're trying to port this to a Docker container based on Alpine Linux with GCC 10.2 and discovered that `__gnu_linux__` is not defined in that case.

So, I've searched for any documentation on the `__gnu_linux__` preprocessor macro but couldn't find anything in the docs of GCC or its preprocessor CPP. The only hint I could find was the following list of pre-defined symbols, but it doesn't mention any documentation: https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/

### Questions

- Where can I find any official documentation about the `__gnu_linux__` preprocessor macro?
- Under which conditions GCC defines it?

### Research so far

By doing a full text search in `/usr` I had a few hits. One is a Boost header file also querying that macro and the two others are the binaries `cc1` and `cc1plus`. I've found out that those are internal tools of GCC implementing the preprocessor for C and C++ respectively, but I couldn't find any official documentation of those. So, I've cloned the GCC source repo and found out it mentions `__gnu_linux__` only once in the change log and contains a few special commits changing a line with `__gnu_linux__`, but none of those makes a definitive statement about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [`gcc/config/linux.h`](https://gcc.gnu.org/git?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/config/linux.h;h=4e1db60fcedaa23499aa9dc79577397c17e91e4e;hb=HEAD#l47:):

```
#define GNU_USER_TARGET_OS_CPP_BUILTINS()                       \
    do {                                                        \
        if (OPTION_GLIBC)                                       \
          builtin_define ("__gnu_linux__");                     \
```

So it's defined only on Linux systems that use glibc.  But [Alpine uses musl libc instead](https://alpinelinux.org/posts/Alpine-Linux-has-switched-to-musl-libc.html).

Also mentioned in [the commit](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commit;f=gcc/config/linux.h;h=74c7025321da74e985e225350c32edd3996a4a1e):

> (`LINUX_TARGET_OS_CPP_BUILTINS`): Define `__gnu_linux__` only for GLIBC.

Comment: Thanks, the hint on Alpine using musl libc explained my initial problem with Alpine. I didn't know that there are alternatives to glibc out there.